# How do you lightness thresh hold with HSL on OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, hsl

There is a project that im working on which required the color white detection, after some research i decided to use covert RGB image to HSL image and thresh hold the lightness to get the color white, im working with openCV so wonder if there is a way to do it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd3MJ.png)

Comment: in opencv is HLS and normally images are loaded as BGR in OpenCV. take a look to [cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).

Comment: Yes i was able to covert the BGR to HLS but what i was stuck at how to filt out the pixel that have lightness attribute too low, so that the image will be left with the shade of color white

Comment: use split to separate the channels (or using numpy slicing), then use threshold in the L one (second channel) and you get a mask with it, then apply the mask to your original image. If you post an example image I can try to give a complete answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it with 4 easy steps:

Convert HLS

```
img = cv2.imread("HLS.png")
imgHLS = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
```

Get the L channel

```
Lchannel = imgHLS[:,:,1]
```

Create the mask

```
#change 250 to lower numbers to include more values as "white"
mask = cv2.inRange(Lchannel, 250, 255)
```

Apply Mask to original image

```
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)
```

This also depends on what is white for you, and you may change the values :) I used inRange in the L channel but you can save one step and do

```
mask = cv2.inRange(imgHLS, np.array([0,250,0]), np.array([255,255,255]))
```

instead of the lines:

```
Lchannel = imgHLS[:,:,1]
mask = cv2.inRange(Lchannel, 250, 255)
```

It is shorter, but I did it the other way first to make it more explicit and to show what I was doing.

Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

The result looks almost as the mask (almost binary), but depending on your lowerbound (I chose 250) you may get even some almost white colors.